# Iterator function for IDisposable items

Tags: c#, iterator, idisposable, enumerator

Suppose I want to create an iterator function that yields `IDisposable` items.

```
IEnumerable<Disposable> GetItems()
{
    yield return new Disposable();
    yield return new Disposable();
}
```

This does not seem ideal for the client code:

```
foreach (var item in source.GetItems())
{
    using (item)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Intuitively, the `using` comes too late. Things could get moved around. One could accidentally insert code *between* the `foreach` and the `using`. Not ideal.

**I am looking for a better alternative!**

One approach that comes to mind is creating the following API instead of an iterator function:

```
// Client
while (source.HasItem)
{
    using (var item = source.GetNextItem())
    {
        // ...
    }
}

// Source
private IEnumerator<Disposable> Enumerator { get; }
private bool? _hasItem;
bool HasItem
{
    get
    {
        if (this._hasItem == null) this._hasItem = this.Enumerator.MoveNext();
        return this._hasItem;
    }
}
Disposable GetNextItem()
{
    if (!this.HasItem) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    this._hasItem = null;
    return this.Enumerator.Current;
}
```

But now it seems that the source *has to become `IDisposable`*! How else would it know when to dispose `Enumerator`? That can be an unpleasant side-effect.

**I am looking for an alternative that feels solid in the client, but that keeps the source from becoming `IDisposable` too.**

*Edit - Clarification: I forgot to mention that some of the content that we need comes from an iterator. Concretely, imagine that we are returning `IDbCommand` instances, which are `IDisposable`. Before returning each command, we need to populate it with some query data, which in turn comes from a simple iterator method.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can expose *only* an `IEnumerator<T>`, which supports nothing but `MoveNext()` and `Current`.

Now, the underlying, *private* iterator function can be streaming, taking care of disposing the items. No invalid operations are introduced to the client - unless they try to store the borrowed objects and try to use them later, where it becomes clear that the objects are already disposed.

```
// Client
using (var itemEnumerator = source.GetItemEnumerator())
{
    while (itemEnumerator.MoveNext())
        var current = itemEnumerator.Current;
}

// Source
IEnumerator<Disposable> GetItemEnumerator() => this.StreamItems().GetEnumerator();
private IEnumerable<Disposable> StreamItems()
{
    while (this.ShouldCreateItem())
    {
        using (var item = this.CreateItem())
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add that using this approach will ensure that if the client code disposes the enumerator before reading all the items, the last item created will get disposed.  Nothing can handle the case where client code abandons (without disposal) an enumerator without reading all the items, but this approach handles all the cases that can be handled.

Comment: You are just reinventing the wheel. This has the same drawbacks as your *iterator function* approach. Ok, the client can't call the *standard* `ToList` method, but it doesn't prevent them to **store** the `itemEnumerator.Current` to some `List` / `Array` etc. and try using it later when it's already disposed.

Comment: @IvanStoev This is miles safer than exposing `ToList()` and friends when you know the items are going to be already disposed. Here, the API helps you to use it correctly. I would be surprised to read the code that combines a loop, `MoveNext()`, and `Current`, with storing `Current` in a *higher-scoped* variable. Even if you took that unlikely route, the error would quickly make sense thanks to the streaming-style API. You'd understand that the items cannot be kept, and instead copy the relevant data to another container.

Comment: @Timo The point is simple. There is no way to stop client of your code doing stupid things. As you can see, in the original post it's the client code which is disposing the returned elements by wrapping them in a  `using` block. And the concern was that some code can be inserted before that block. What I suggested was a way the **client** implement the same without that possibility. Nothing less, nothing more. Implementing `foreach` disposing the element after consuming it.

Comment: @Timo What about a code that uses `MoveNext` and puts `Current` in a higher scoped variable, that's basically what the standard `ToList` implementation would be after removing the compiler `foreach` magic :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Good explanation. Your example of adding each item to another collection (manual `ToList()`, so to speak) is realistic, I agree. So we have a trade-off between requiring the client to remember to dispose the collection's *individual items*, vs. creating the possibility to store a "borrowed" object that will be disposed by the owner. My personal preference goes to the latter, the reason being that I am convinced that people are going to forget disposing individual items (undetected problem), but they'll fail to use the disposed borrowed items (detected problem). This can be solved.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. By reinventing the wheel I mean reinventing the `foreach` pattern. Now your client will be forced to use something that compiler generates for `foreach` operator. First, wrap the returned `IEnumerator<T>` in a `using` block. Then access the `Current` property only inside the body of the `while` loop. But `itemEnumerator` is in scope, so it can easily be used incorrectly before/after the loop. All this is prevented by `foreach` statement. So solving one potential issue opens another :) Anyway, it was good discussion and the decision (as well as the problem) is all yours :)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, the following pattern works for you

```
foreach (var item in source.GetItems())
{
    using (item)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

but the potential problem is putting some code outside the `using` block. So why don't you just wrap that logic in a custom extensions method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtennisons
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> WithUsing<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        where T : IDisposable
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            using (item)
                yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you ensure the item is wrapped in `using` block *before** returning it to the caller, so there is no way the caller to insert code before/after it. The C# compiler generated code ensures the `item.Dispose` is called in either `MoveNext` or `Dispose` method of the `IEnumerator<T>` (in case the iteration ends earlier).

The usage would be to append `.WithUsing()` call instead of `using` block where needed:

```
foreach (var item in source.GetItems().WithUsing())
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: For the `using` in your extension method, when *exactly* does it call `Dispose()` on the current item? I am assuming when either **(A)** the next item is asked for (causing the method to continue beyond the yield line, and thus out of the `using` block), or **(B)** the iterator is disposed (e.g. because the client `foreach` loop breaks). Particularly the last part is an assumption.

Comment: It's indeed the way you assume. In the next call to `MoveNext` or in `Dispose` method of the enumerator in case loop exits earlier.

Comment: I'm now on the fence about introducing a `LINQ`-ish extension method with side-effects, because such methods are expected to be side-effect free. (I recognize that your solution answers the question.)

Comment: Correct. But so does your original and modified code - disposing something that they don't own. What if the source is `List` of disposable objects which can be iterated many times? It's basically the same side effect, so no difference. The user code either  does that or not, by either original `using` block inside the `foreach`, and now by wrapping the enumerable before `foreach`-ing it. There is no difference in my view.

Comment: Instead of `AsDisposable`, you can call it `WithUsing` if you wish :)

Comment: That's the point of the `GetNextItem()` method: create and return something that is then owned by the caller. You're right about the `foreach` with the `using`, which *is* disposing things it does not own. That actually seems to provide the answer: The iterator function itself can take responsibility for disposing each item when the next is requested. Let me post this as a separate answer, so that it can be discussed.

Comment: Still there is no difference. In both cases the *caller* takes the responsibility - by wrapping/not wrapping  the body with  `using` block or calling/not calling `AsDisposable` method.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator function itself can take responsibility for placing a using (i.e. disposing the current item when the next is requested).

```
IEnumerable<Disposable> GetItems()
{
    // Assumming CreateItems() is an iterator as well
    foreach (var item in this.CreateItems())
        using (item) yield return item;
}
```

As a result, we will essentially have a streaming-only iterator. Methods like `ToList()` become meaningless, because only one item is usable at a time.

Unfortunately, this does create room for error.